# Libsigsegv not working with pthread when a stack overflow happens

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, stack-overflow

The libsigsegv [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/) says that to use the libsigserv with threads its necessary to call the pthread_sigmask and the pthread_setcancelstate, but I dont know where to use it. I have the code below which I'm compiling with g++ under Linux and of course I can't trap the thread stack overflow. How should I call these functions? What else am I doing wrong? Is it possible to trap the SIGSEGV caused by a stackoverflow in a thread?

At the `main` function I have:

```
stackoverflow_install_handler(&stackoverflow_function, myStack, 16 * 1024);
```

the `stackoferflow_function` prints *"Signal trapped"*

and the thread function calls a infinite recursive function which causes the stack overflow.

Thanks in advance.